# Что это за синтаксис в передаче параметра {{blocks["menu_footer_categories"]}}?

Tags: php, html, mysql, разметка, семантика

Моя задача сделать микроразметку для сайта, я нашел нужный файл, хочу прописать микроразметку для контактных данных, однако здесь имеется синтаксис, который я ранее не встречал, помогите разобраться!

```
<div class="ig_footer_block_2">
        {{blocks["menu_footer_categories"]}}
</div>
```

Comment: У jinja2 такой же синтаксис )

Comment: Да у многих шаблонизаторов такой же синтаксис

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на синтаксис [twig](http://x-twig.ru/for_template_designers/) шаблонизатора.

Переменные

```
{{ foo.bar }}
{{ foo['bar'] }}
```